# dict.has_key(somekey) does not work equally as somekey in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I recently encountered a weird problem with python dictionary while playing with Beautifulsoup. My code looks like this.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.msn.com")
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
anchors = soup.findAll('a')
for a in anchors:
    if not a.has_key('href') == 'href' in a:
        print a
```

It actually printed out a lot of links, in which has_key works differently as 'in'.

Can anybody explain Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `if` expression is not doing what you think it does. You may want to add some parenthesis, right now it is read as `not ((a.has_key('href') == 'href') in a)`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want:

```
if not a.has_key('href'):
```

Or a much Pythonic way of checking this:

```
if 'href' not in a:
```

`has_key()` works like the `in` keyword (as the other answers pointed out, you forgot parenthesis) but `has_key()` is [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has%5Fkey) and not supported in Python 3.x. So you should always use `in`.

Comment: I think that should be `if 'href' not in a`, to be most readable

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the precedence of operators:

```
>>> a = {'a': 5, 'b': 6}
>>> a.has_key('a')
True
>>> 'a' in a
True
>>> a.has_key('a') == 'a' in a
False
>>> a.has_key('a') == ('a' in a)
True
>>> (a.has_key('a') == 'a') in a
False
```

So in your case

```
if not a.has_key('href') == 'href' in a:
        print a
```

actually means

```
if not (a.has_key('href') == 'href') in a:
        print a
```

while you want to chech

```
if not a.has_key('href') == ('href' in a):
        print a
```

Furthermore the thing with deprecating has_key and not supporting it in python3. If you have a choice, dump python2 all together and go for 3.x

Comment: Thanks for pointing out precedence problem. I have those parentheses in my original code and removed them when I post the code.  Even if I put back the parenthesis, the problem is still there. The has_key() works differently than in. I figured out the problem eventually and found out that the 'a' variable is not of type dict but instead of class BeautifulSoup.Tag. That class implements a method called has_key(). Before inspecting its type, I mistakenly thought it was a dict. So has_key() works but the in keyword doesn't.

Comment: oh, guess duck typing can bite you sometimes :D